# Removing noise from image C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, bitmap, imagefilter

Newbie here. Have an image I added noise on image, and them i need to clear image with noise(or something like that). The unnoising algorythm is next:

> If the brightness of the pixel is greater than the average brightness of the local neighborhood, then the brightness of the pixel is replaced with the average brightness of the surroundings.

```
  public void AdjustBrightness(Bitmap Image, int limit)
    {
        try
        {
            int width = newImage.Width;
            int height = newImage.Height;
            for (int x = 0; x < width - 1;x++)
            {
                if (x - 1 > 0 && x < width)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < height - 1;y++)
                    {
                        if (y - 1 > 0 && y < height)
                        {
                            int local1 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y - 1)).R +
                                     0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y - 1)).G +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y - 1)).B);
                            int local2 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y).R) + 0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y).B));
                            int local3 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y + 1).R) +
                                     0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y + 1).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x - 1, y + 1).B));
                            int local4 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y - 1).R) + 0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y - 1).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y - 1).B));
                            int local6 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y + 1).R) + 0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y + 1).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y + 1).B));
                            int local7 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y - 1).R) +
                                     0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y - 1).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y - 1).B));
                            int local8 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y).R) + 0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y).B));
                            int local9 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1).R) +
                                     0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x + 1, y + 1).B));
                            int localAll =
                                (int)
                                    ((local1 + local2 + local3 + local4 + local6 + local7 + local8 + local9)*0.125);
                            int LOCAL5 =
                                (int)
                                    (0.3*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y).R) + 0.59*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y).G) +
                                     0.11*(newImage.GetPixel(x, y).B))+1;

                                int p1 = newImage.GetPixel(x, y).R;
                                int p3 = newImage.GetPixel(x, y).B;
                                int p2 = newImage.GetPixel(x, y).G;
                                int pixelR = (p1*(localAll/LOCAL5));
                                int pixelG = (p2*(localAll/LOCAL5));
                                int pixelB = (p3*(localAll/LOCAL5));
                                if (Math.Abs(LOCAL5 - localAll) > limit)
                                {
                                    newImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(pixelR, pixelG, pixelB));
                                }

                            pictureIn.Image = newImage;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);

        }

        finally
        {
            newImage.Save("F:/filter.jpeg");
        }
    }
```

In this line I have a problem: System.ArgumentException, some values of variables are greater than 255:

```
newImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(pixelR, pixelG, pixelB));
```

Comment: So if the value **is** greater than 255, what do you want to do?

Comment: Check `pixelR = pixelR > 255 ? 255 : pixelR` for each component value (RGB).

Comment: @stuartd I want the filter to work, but a final image isn't processed the filter and noise isn't removed.

Comment: Look into the offending value: If it is off by one simply adjust to 255. If it is off by a lot more your calcualtions are wrong. Use your debugger! We can't do that for you.. Btw, there is a Color.GetBrightness function and also: If you don't want to use it you stil should create one of your own to reduce the code size and get rid of all the redundancies!!!